# Construct a circle from set of points in 2D space. 80% of the given points, lie on the circles's circumference. The rest 20% are garbage values.

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

**How can I identify the circle ?**
I have a set of points(70) of which 80% percent always fall on the circumference of the circle and the rest 20% are garbage values.

**What else do I have ?**
A 320*240 matrix in which, only these points have value "1", while the others have value "0".

Is there any way I can go about solving this. If not solve, at least reduce the problem somehow ?

Answer (score 2):

I've dealt with a similar problem, detecting circles in 3D geometry. My solution, which works reasonably well, samples three points from the available set of points, using them to calculate candidate circles. Once enough of the candidates agree, the result is determined to be a circle.

The calculation itself takes place in a 2D plane, so points need to be projected beforehand. The actual function is this:

```
bool GetCircleCenter (const cPoint2 &P1, const cPoint2 &P2, const cPoint2 &P3, cPoint2 &Center)
{   const float X1 = P2.X - P1.X;
    const float X2 = P3.X - P1.X;
    const float Y1 = P2.Y - P1.Y;
    const float Y2 = P3.Y - P1.Y;

    const float Area = (X1 * Y2 - Y1 * X2);
    if (ABS (Area) < 0.0000001)
        return false;

    const float L1 = (P2 - P1).Length ();
    const float L2 = (P3 - P1).Length ();

    Center.X = P1.X + (Y2 * L1 * L1 - Y1 * L2 * L2) / (2 * Area);
    Center.Y = P1.Y + (X1 * L2 * L2 - X2 * L1 * L1) / (2 * Area);
    return true;
}
```

Source code is from page 800 of this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Computer-Graphics-Morgan-Kaufmann/dp/1558605940](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605940)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution should be the [Circle Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform). You accumulate possible circle placements in a large 3D array of all circle parameters. Since most points are on the circumference, the maximum should be very clear.

If you had much lower numbers of inliers, you could still solve this problem with [Random sample consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC). Since three points define a circle, you are very likely to find three inliers after a few trials.